# How to debug unhandled win32 exception in WinJS Win8 store app

Tags: windows-8.1, winjs

I have added Microsoft Ad SDK to my WinJS app and it crashes if I navigate away from my default.html page too fast.

```
<script src="/MSAdvertisingJS/ads/ad.js"></script>
```

If I comment out this line it does not crash. If I navigate to the default.html page and wait 10 seconds (possibly less) then it does NOT crash. It only crashes if I land on the page and immediately navigate to another page in the app. I set the destination page to be a blank html page and it still crashes.

Any ideas how I can debug further to see what is causing the issue?

[image]

Debugging it gives this call stack.

```
>   kernel32.dll!00007ffc2c9c83a6() Unknown
    combase.dll!00007ffc2e6a65b0()  Unknown
    twinapi.appcore.dll!00007ffc1b5847ac()  Unknown
    twinapi.appcore.dll!00007ffc1b58480f()  Unknown
    combase.dll!00007ffc2e6a61c2()  Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffc0a8a2b2d()  Unknown
```

I've further narrowed down the issue to being related to the link I'm navigating with.

```
    <a href="home2.html">
        <h1 class="mid">Start</h1>
    </a>

    <a href="home2.html">
        <img src="images/d20.png" alt="d20 image" />
    </a>
```

The first link crashes, the second doesn't. I changed the H1 tag into a span and it no longer crashes an early navigation. A few mins later it starts crashing again after adding a Div.

thanks

Comment: how can you tell it's a win32 exception? Maybe is a handled exception... what message do you get (if any)

Comment: Have added screenshot of the error. I have tried debugging it but its not .Net code.

Comment: I've recreated the crash in the Ad sample project and can share the file (not sure you can upload files to SO). Will see if I can get some support from Microsoft

Comment: you can share it via OneDrive or other file sharing service... I'll be happy to take a look at it

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6olxyogomu6v7ai/Show%20Ads%20Using%20the%20A1.zip Shared via dropbox. To reproduce, click the url quickly on loading and it should crash. Be interesting to see if you can reproduce it.

Comment: yeap, I did reproduce it :( will take a deeper look at it but I think you should file a bug at http://connect.microsoft.com. Also make sure you send what's found in the Event Viewer