# Unhandled exception in WWAHost in Cordova APP using Angular

Tags: angularjs, windows, cordova, visual-studio-2013, winjs

I'm currently developing a windows modern app using Foundation for Apps and cordova. The app crashes in many ways during navigation, sometimes even immediately after running it.

The crash is this one [image]

And i can't manage to debug it in any way.

I've tried setting up a window.onerror and a WinJS.Application.onerror catch all function with no results. Apparently the crash happens at a lower level. I've also inspected the event viewer but no info are available.

What happens is apparently similar to this question: [How to debug unhandled win32 exception in WinJS Win8 store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521856/how-to-debug-unhandled-win32-exception-in-winjs-win8-store-app) which is unfortunately unsolved.

What are my options here?

Comment: Which OS version are you running this on?

Are you running with the script debugger attached, and you see this error without any script exceptions being hit? (also, make sure you set VS to break in when ever a JS exception is *thrown*, not left unhandled, and try running these scenarios).

If you say Yes to this dialog and let the native JIT debugger attach, what is the callstack and which exception code is it?

Comment: Windows 8.1. The error varies, most of the times it's this one:
Unhandled exception at 0x538448A7 (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000038.
Sometimes it happens even when the app starts, sometimes when i open the DOM inspector, other times simply by using the app. No other JS errors are shown. I tried both enable and disabling throwing all JS exceptions, with no changes.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a native debugger and getting a callstack for the exception? You can do this in VS by setting the debugger type to Native or Native With Script. You may need to enable symbol loading from the MS Symbol Servers to get a complete stack.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with **Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10 and cordova 5.1.1** when I transfer the project to another dev environment. It only occurs at the Windows-x64 app build configuration for the local machine.

After successful building, the app window launches shortly and after that, the win32 exception like the screenshot from sPoz came up. It was reproducible every time.

I try to repair Visual Studio and also I checked the environment variable from my solution as it is described in [this Microsoft Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811191). But I had no luck.

Nothing helped, but simply open the config.xml file and change the Windows Target Version from "Windows 10" to "Windows 8.1" solved the problem and I could run the app with no error:

[image]

After that I can turn back to "Windows 10" and everything is fine. This was reproducable on two dev machines.

I do not exactly know if the moved project was the source of the problem and maybe the rewritten config.xml triggers any rebuild mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are hitting an issue related to DOM Ex WWAHost.exe error on Windows 8.1 (apparently fixed on Win10). There is a workaround that should work for most apps; before you click around and get the WWAHost.exe exception, close the DOM Explorer window. This should enable you to debug by hitting breakpoints, etc. If you need to use DOM Ex against a Windows target, you might need try debugging against a remote device (see Kenneth's suggestion here: [Why is Cordova Windows 8 app causing an unhandled win32 exception occurred in wwahost.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464522/why-is-cordova-windows-8-app-causing-an-unhandled-win32-exception-occurred-in-ww))

Comment: Thanks Mike.. I found this question because I am suffering the same issue.. clicking things in certain orders works and others just crashes as above. I closed the DOM explorer and it doesn't crash any more (in the same way).. sorry I can't mark you as an answer but I +1'd your helpful suggestion.. many thanks - Brett

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to develop the app ? The Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova ? Or Cordova with CLI ?
If you are using the plugin, you must launch the generated WP project to debug. The debug of WP app is not supported currently with the plugin.

Comment: I'm using the generated project in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Okey,

Do you use plugins ? If yes, can  you remove them  ? beacause if the exception is on C# code, you can't handle the errors

Comment: I am and I will try removing them. But they're all written in JS, so I doubt that'll change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error during development of cordova windows tablet application, using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. So far, I was doing try to close DOM-Explorer and use breakpoints and javascript console. After that, while searching javascript intellisense issues with Visual Studio, I figured out that my problem **was fixed**. What I did to get rid of this problem is that:

- **Open Tools > Options**
- **Select Text Editor > Javascript > Intellisense > References**
- **Add following references ( angular.intellisense.js, domWeb.js, domWindows_8.1.js )**.

I don't know what are the correct reference files, but with these 3 reference files added, my problem has been solved.