# Why is Cordova Windows 8 app causing an unhandled win32 exception occurred in wwahost.exe?

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-8.1

We're building out an app in Cordova via VS 2013 for Windows 8.1. When the user is "clicking" an anchor tag on one of our pages we get "an unhandled win32 exception occurred in wwahost.exe".

We checked our registery for this issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811191 and everything is correct by default.

According to some Google searches this is the only solution we can find.

In the debugger -

"Call Stack":

```
mshtml.dll!CDocument::Doc(void) Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CAttribute::GetNSAtomTable() Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CAttribute::NamespaceURI(void)   Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CAttribute::get_namespaceURI()   Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CAttribute::get_ie9_nodeValue()  Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CAttribute::get_ie9_value(unsigned short * *)    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CDOMMutationEvent::PrepareEvent()    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::Dispatch()    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::DispatchDOMAttrModified(class CElement *,unsigned short const *,struct PROPERTYDESC const *,long,class CNSAttr *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short,bool)  Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::DispatchDOMAttrModified(class CElement *,unsigned short const *,struct PROPERTYDESC const *,long,class CNSAttr *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short)   Unknown
    mshtml.dll!BASICPROPPARAMS::SetStyleComponentProperty() Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CCSSStyleDeclaration::put_StyleComponentLocalHelper()    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CWritableCSSStyleDeclaration::put_transitionDuration(unsigned short *)   Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CFastDOM::CCSSStyleDeclaration::Trampoline_Set_transitionDuration(void *,struct CallInfo,...)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction ()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptExternalFunction::ExternalFunctionThunk()    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction ()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::HelperOrLibraryMethodWrapper<1,class <lambda_f3fb5c5fabf75a41a43766851a4fc31b> >(class Js::ScriptContext *,class <lambda_f3fb5c5fabf75a41a43766851a4fc31b>)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::ScriptContext::ProfileModeThunk_DebugModeWrapper(class Js::JavascriptFunction *,class Js::ScriptContext *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments &) Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::ScriptContext::DebugProfileProbeThunk(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!<lambda>(void)()   Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptOperators::CallSetter()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptOperators::OP_SetElementI()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_SetElementI_NoFastPath(struct Js::OpLayoutElementI const *,void *,enum Js::PropertyOperationFlags)   Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_ProfiledSetElementI()    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::ProcessWithDebugging(void)  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::DebugProcess(void)  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
    000000045d541fbb()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction ()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::ScriptContext::DebugProfileProbeThunk(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction ()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_CallCommon<struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> >(struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> const *,class Js::RecyclableObject *,unsigned int)  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_ProfileCallCommon<struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> >(struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> const *,class Js::RecyclableObject *,unsigned int,unsigned short)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_ProfiledCallI<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte>(struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> const *,unsigned int)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::ProcessWithDebugging(void)  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::DebugProcess(void)  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
    000000045d541943()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction ()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::ScriptContext::DebugProfileProbeThunk(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction ()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_CallCommon<struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> >(struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> const *,class Js::RecyclableObject *,unsigned int)  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_ProfileCallCommon<struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> >(struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> const *,class Js::RecyclableObject *,unsigned int,unsigned short)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_ProfiledCallI<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte>(struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> const *,unsigned int)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::ProcessWithDebugging(void)  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::DebugProcess(void)  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!BailOutRecord::BailOutHelper() Unknown
    jscript9.dll!BailOutRecord::BailOutCommonNoCodeGen(class Js::JavascriptCallStackLayout *,class BailOutRecord const *,unsigned int,void *,enum IR::BailOutKind,void * *,struct BailOutRecord::BailOutReturnValue *)  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!BailOutRecord::BailOutCommon(class Js::JavascriptCallStackLayout *,class BailOutRecord const *,unsigned int,void *,enum IR::BailOutKind,struct BailOutRecord::BailOutReturnValue *)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!BailOutRecord::BailOut()   Unknown
    000000046a05d891()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction ()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::ScriptContext::DebugProfileProbeThunk(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction ()  Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallRootFunction() Unknown
    jscript9.dll!ScriptSite::CallRootFunction(class Js::JavascriptFunction *,struct Js::Arguments,struct IServiceProvider *,void * *)   Unknown
    jscript9.dll!ScriptSite::Execute(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::Arguments *,struct IServiceProvider *,void * *)    Unknown
    jscript9.dll!JavascriptDispatch::InvokeOnSelf() Unknown
    jscript9.dll!JavascriptDispatch::InvokeEx() Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CBase::InvokeDispatchWithThis()  Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::InvokeNonLegacyListener(class CBase *,struct IDispatch *,struct IDispatch *,struct tagVARIANT *,struct tagDISPPARAMS *,struct tagEXCEPINFO *,struct tagVARIANT *) Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CListenerDispatch::InvokeDispatch(class CBase *,class CEventListener *,struct DISPATCHINFO *,struct tagVARIANT *)    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CListenerDispatch::Invoke()  Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::_InvokeListeners()    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::_DispatchBubblePhase(class CDOMEvent *,struct DISPATCHINFO *) Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::Dispatch()    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::DispatchMouseEvent()  Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CElement::FireStdEvent_MouseHelper() Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CElement::FireStdEventOnMessage()    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CDoc::PumpMessage()  Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CMouseHandler::HandleSyntheticMessage()  Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CTouchHelper::PumpSynthesizedMessage(class CMessage *,bool)  Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CTouchHelper::PrepareAndPump(class CMessage *,class CMessage const *,class TOUCHCONTEXT *)   Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CTouchHelper::FireMouseEventMessage(class CMessage const *,class TOUCHCONTEXT *,unsigned int,bool)   Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CTouchHelper::FireMouseDownMessages()    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CTouchHelper::FirePointerDownMessages(class CMessage const *,class TOUCHCONTEXT *)   Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CTouchHelper::GenerateInputEvents()  Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CTouchHelper::OnPointerMessage() Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CTouchHelper::HandleMessage(unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64,__int64 *) Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CInputManager::HandleMessage(unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64,__int64 *,bool *) Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CDoc::OnWindowMessage()  Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CServer::WndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)  Unknown
    user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
    user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.dll!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages(void * hEventWait) Line 321   C++
    Windows.UI.dll!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents(Windows::UI::Core::CoreProcessEventsOption options) Line 390   C++
    WWAHost.exe!CoreWindowDispatcher::RunMessageLoop(struct Windows::UI::Core::ICoreWindow *)   Unknown
    WWAHost.exe!WebInstance::Run(void)  Unknown
    twinapi.appcore.dll!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run(void) Unknown
    twinapi.appcore.dll!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Uninitialize(void)    Unknown
    SHCore.dll!StrRetToBSTR ()  Unknown
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk () Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart () Unknown
```

and the Output:

```
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WWAHost.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wininet.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MrmCoreR.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\BCP47Langs.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rometadata.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ninput.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d2d1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DWrite.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\actxprxy.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igd10iumd64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d10_1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ncrypt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d10_1core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdusc64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\secur32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msimtf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dcomp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WwaApi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug\pdm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug\pdmproxy100.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug\VSDebugScriptAgent120.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\jscript9.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Script Diagnostics\amd64\DiagnosticsTap.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mlang.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecs.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\PhotoMetadataHandler.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecsExt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winnsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\t2embed.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfplat.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\RTWorkQ.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MFMediaEngine.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Media.MediaControl.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profext.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\xmllite.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sxs.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MMDevAPI.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Devices.Enumeration.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DevDispItemProvider.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\StructuredQuery.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MSWB7.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Devices.Enumeration.ps.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleacc.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\UIAnimation.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x19b8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF98C21A67B (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.

First-chance exception at 0x00007FF98C21A67B (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF98C21A67B (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.

First-chance exception at 0x00007FF98C21A67B (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.
The thread 0x2880 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF98C21A67B (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.

First-chance exception at 0x00007FF98C21A67B (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF98C21A67B (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.

First-chance exception at 0x00007FF98C21A67B (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF98C21A67B (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.

First-chance exception at 0x00007FF98C21A67B (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF98C21A67B (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.
```

We get that `First-chance exception...` error every time we view the debugger. Not sure if it's related to the app or an visual studio issue.

In our cordova code this is the html that we are using. Selecting the `a` tag is what cases the error.

```
<div class="case-study-wrapper active nanowrap nanoslim convention-center" data-has-video="yes">
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
        <a data-linked-content="case-studies.html?subsec=#ix-center" data-content-id="ix-center" href="#"></a>
        <img src="img/installation-logos/ixcenter-logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <p>IX Center</p>
        <p><strong>NanoWrap and NanoSlim</strong></p>
        <p class="industry">Convention Centers</p>
    </div>
    <div class="video-icon visible">
        <div class="ion-ios-videocam"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the `data-` attributes trigger `eventlisteners` and other functions based on their values.

Comment: Can you post the details of the exception, stack etc... Might help people to point to a possible problem as there is very little here to help people help you.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but when you say "stack" I assume you mean what's in the "call stack" correct?

Comment: Correct.  Your question does not have a lot of information to point to a problem, and there is not any source code, so any additional information provided might be helpful to someone looking at your issue.

Comment: Added the call stack and output. The original app was built buy a previous dev and bit a bit twisted in its construction. Any source code I add would be way too long and way too difficult to explain. Especially without know which where the issue is coming from.

Comment: You can use the sample project at https://github.com/Mikejo5001/ionic-sidemenu-vstools and reproduce the issue.  I am running this with VS 2015 RC and trying to debug on my local Windows 8.1 machine using the Windows-AnyCPU target.  If you click on the menu button on the left hand side the slide out menu will appear.  If you select the menu button again to dismiss the menu you will get the same exception and stack as listed above.

Comment: @ChrisW. were you able to figure out what caused the issue?

Comment: I've added the HTML we use in Cordova in hopes that might give better insight

Comment: Nah not yet, still looking into it also unfortunately.

Comment: we removed all the `data-` and classes to remove styling and click functions and we still get a crash. Would a memory issue cause this kind of crash?

Comment: @dcp3450 were you able to find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

There is a quicker workaround for this that should work for most apps; before you click around and get the WWAHost.exe exception, close the DOM Explorer window. This should enable you to debug by hitting breakpoints, etc. If you need to use DOM Ex (against a Windows target), I'd suggest trying Kenneth's solution.

Answer (score 2):

The only work around that I have found that has allowed me to debug Hybrid Windows Store Apps has been to use remote debugging on anther machine.  Kind of a pain if you don't have two machines, but you may be able to use a virtual machine as your remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with input tags in Windows 8.1 with my Cordova app. Seemed to only happen to users with tablets using touch screens. Here's my code for a simple image upload/preview button.

HTML:

`<label class="lbl-upload" for="uploadFile1">
    <img class="img-upload" src="img/add-photos.png" id="uploadBtn1" />
 </label>
 <input type="file" name="uploadFile1" id="uploadFile1" />
 <img id="img1" src="#" alt="your image" />`

JS:

```
var coors;

$('#uploadFile1').change(function() {
  clearTimeout(coors);
  coors = setTimeout(function() {
        var reader = new FileReader(); 
        var file = document.querySelector('#uploadFile1').files[0];
        var preview = document.querySelector('#img1');
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            preview.src = reader.result;
        }
        if (file){
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        else {
            preview.src = "";
        }
  }, 2000);
});
```

For whatever reason a delay is needed for touch screens. Not very pretty but gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when VS crashed it became corrupted. I reran the install and chose "repair" and now it's fine.