# Access violation while remote debugging windows application on surface

Tags: windows, cordova, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using Visual Studio cordova template for developing a Windows application. The application is targeted for windows Surface.

When launching the application from Visual Studio 2015 with remote debugging on windows surface, application is crashing everytime. However, the app works fine when running without attaching debugger.

From the event viewer in windows surface I can see some exceptions :
Faulting application name: wwahost.exe, version: 6.3.9600.17415
Faulting module name: MSHTML.dll, version: 11.0.9600.17842

And in Visual studio only this comes when the application crashes :
WWAHost.exe has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'

Remote debugger tool I am using is downloaded from here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46874

And the issue is occurring with Surface Pro 3. But when I tried to debug the same application with Surface Pro 2, the application works fine. Is there any setting for Surface Pro 3 for debugging?. Or if it is a known issue, is there any workaround ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run into this error when attaching the debugger normally against Local Machine or Simulator via F5? If you do, you may be running into this issue: [Why is Cordova Windows 8 app causing an unhandled win32 exception occurred in wwahost.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464522/why-is-cordova-windows-8-app-causing-an-unhandled-win32-exception-occurred-in-ww/30739871#30739871). If that is the issue, you may be able to workaround it by closing DOM Explorer window before you hit the error (this error is usually seen when loading a new page).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- right click the startup project
- properties
- debug tab
- check 'Enable native code debugging'

This one worked for me.