# Winjs app with angularJS crashes on startup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows-8.1, winjs

I am currently developing a WinJS app with AngularJS.

When i try to run or start this app, on some devices (not on all devices although they are the same model, with the same configuration..), the app crashes immediately after startup with an unhandled win32 exception occurred in wwahost.exe.

Output window:

```
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WWAHost.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wininet.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MrmCoreR.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\BCP47Langs.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ninput.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rometadata.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d2d1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DWrite.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\actxprxy.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvumdshimx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvinitx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igd10iumd64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ncrypt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdusc64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\secur32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msimtf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dcomp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WwaApi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug\pdm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug\pdmproxy100.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug\VSDebugScriptAgent120.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\jscript9.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Script Diagnostics\amd64\DiagnosticsTap.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mlang.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profext.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\xmllite.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sxs.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecs.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vaultcli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winhttp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winnsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\schannel.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ncryptsslp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gpapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptnet.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WWAHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Wldap32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x2950 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFFBF8587F (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.
```

The stack trace:

```
>   mshtml.dll!CDocument::Doc(void) Unknown
mshtml.dll!CAttribute::GetNSAtomTable() Unknown
mshtml.dll!CAttribute::NamespaceURI(void)   Unknown
mshtml.dll!CAttribute::get_namespaceURI()   Unknown
mshtml.dll!CAttribute::get_ie9_nodeValue()  Unknown
mshtml.dll!CAttribute::get_ie9_value(unsigned short * *)    Unknown
mshtml.dll!CFastDOM::CAttr::Trampoline_Get_value()  Unknown
jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptExternalFunction::ExternalFunctionThunk()    Unknown
jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::ScriptContext::DebugProfileProbeThunk(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!<lambda>(void)()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::DictionaryTypeHandlerBase<unsigned short>::GetProperty()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::DynamicObject::GetProperty(void *,int,void * *,class Js::PropertyValueInfo *,class Js::ScriptContext *)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::CustomExternalObject::GetPropertyImpl<1>() Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::CustomExternalObject::GetProperty(void *,int,void * *,class Js::PropertyValueInfo *,class Js::ScriptContext *) Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptOperators::GetProperty_Internal<0>() Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptOperators::PatchGetValueNoFastPath(class Js::FunctionBody *,unsigned int,void *,int,class Js::ScriptContext *)   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_ProfiledGetProperty<struct Js::OpLayoutElementCP_OneByte const >(struct Js::OpLayoutElementCP_OneByte const *)   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::ProcessWithDebugging(void)  Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::DebugProcess(void)  Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::ScriptContext::DebugProfileProbeThunk(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_CallCommon<struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> >(struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> const *,class Js::RecyclableObject *,unsigned int)  Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_ProfileCallCommon<struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> >(struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> const *,class Js::RecyclableObject *,unsigned int,unsigned short)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_ProfiledCallI<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte>(struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> const *,unsigned int)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::ProcessWithDebugging(void)  Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::DebugProcess(void)  Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
0000002c7dcd1f83()  Unknown
jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::ScriptContext::DebugProfileProbeThunk(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::EntryCall()    Unknown
jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::HelperOrLibraryMethodWrapper<1,class <lambda_f3fb5c5fabf75a41a43766851a4fc31b> >(class Js::ScriptContext *,class <lambda_f3fb5c5fabf75a41a43766851a4fc31b>)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::ScriptContext::ProfileModeThunk_DebugModeWrapper(class Js::JavascriptFunction *,class Js::ScriptContext *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments &) Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::ScriptContext::DebugProfileProbeThunk(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_CallCommon<struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> >(struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> const *,class Js::RecyclableObject *,unsigned int)  Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_ProfileCallCommon<struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> >(struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> const *,class Js::RecyclableObject *,unsigned int,unsigned short)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_ProfiledCallI<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte>(struct Js::OpLayoutDynamicProfile<struct Js::OpLayoutCallI_OneByte> const *,unsigned int)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::ProcessWithDebugging(void)  Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::DebugProcess(void)  Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
0000002c7dcd1f93()  Unknown
jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::ScriptContext::DebugProfileProbeThunk(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!amd64_CallFunction()   Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>(class Js::RecyclableObject *,void * (*)(class Js::RecyclableObject *,struct Js::CallInfo,...),struct Js::Arguments)    Unknown
jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallRootFunction() Unknown
jscript9.dll!ScriptSite::CallRootFunction(class Js::JavascriptFunction *,struct Js::Arguments,struct IServiceProvider *,void * *)   Unknown
jscript9.dll!ScriptSite::Execute()  Unknown
jscript9.dll!ScriptEngineBase::Execute()    Unknown
mshtml.dll!CListenerDispatch::InvokeVar()   Unknown
mshtml.dll!CListenerDispatch::Invoke()  Unknown
mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::_InvokeListeners()    Unknown
mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::_InvokeListenersOnWindow(class CDOMEvent *,struct DISPATCHINFO *) Unknown
mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::_InvokeListeners()    Unknown
mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::Dispatch()    Unknown
mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::DispatchEvent(struct PROPERTYDESC_BASIC const *,class CBase *,class CSecurityContext *,long)  Unknown
mshtml.dll!COmWindowProxy::Fire_onload()    Unknown
mshtml.dll!CMarkup::OnLoadStatusDone()  Unknown
mshtml.dll!CMarkup::OnLoadStatus()  Unknown
mshtml.dll!CProgSink::DoUpdate()    Unknown
mshtml.dll!GlobalWndOnMethodCall()  Unknown
mshtml.dll!GlobalWndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64) Unknown
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  Unknown
Windows.UI.dll!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages(void * hEventWait) Line 321   C++
Windows.UI.dll!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents(Windows::UI::Core::CoreProcessEventsOption options) Line 390   C++
WWAHost.exe!CoreWindowDispatcher::RunMessageLoop(struct Windows::UI::Core::ICoreWindow *)   Unknown
WWAHost.exe!WebInstance::Run(void)  Unknown
twinapi.appcore.dll!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run(void) Unknown
twinapi.appcore.dll!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Uninitialize(void)    Unknown
SHCore.dll!StrRetToBSTR()   Unknown
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  Unknown
```

The issue is very similar to [Why is Cordova Windows 8 app causing an unhandled win32 exception occurred in wwahost.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464522/why-is-cordova-windows-8-app-causing-an-unhandled-win32-exception-occurred-in-ww), but the DOM inspector isn't open and it happens on startup.

Anyone who has an idea what it can be?

Comment: same issue, no resolution.

We're talking to MS Premier support, who hasn't been helpful so far-- 3 days in.

Did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: @dethSwatch any updates on this?

Comment: @gotomanners No resolution- MS is of the opinion that it's an angular issue, but that's despite the fact that it worked fine up until a series of Windows patches. If we run it without those patches, then it works as expected. For various reasons, we can't send them the dump file, so they're a bit hamstrung. Also, it doesn't always crash- just mostly. I'll post more when I've got an update.

Comment: @dethSwatch Thanks. I'll keep an eye on this thread and will post if i find anything.

Comment: @gotomanners same story here, no resolution. The app is running on devices windows update disabled..