# WWHost.exe exception when trying to debug using VS2015 Cordova tools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I get the following exceptions everytime I try to debug a cordova app on Visual Studio 2015. If I close the dom element navigator before the exception is thrown I can continiue normally.

Any ideas?

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007ffe68c39bef (mshtml.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.
```

I tried repairing with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the following fixed my issue.

1. Change Target Version to Windows 10
2. Build.
3. Change Target Version to Windows 8.1
4. Clean & Build

I originally had the target Windows version set to Windows 8.1. I am building on Windows 8.1.

It looks like Microsoft fixed this issue by disabling the DOM Navigator on 8.1 since that is what seemed to be causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Are you on Win8.1? My understanding is this is specific to Win8, so if you upgrade to Win10 it should go away. Also, you could Shift+F5 to start app without debugging.

Comment: Yes, I am on 8.1.Is there any other workaround. Do you have any links? Thanks

Comment: No official docs. This is probably most helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851663/unhandled-exception-in-wwahost-in-cordova-app-using-angular